# Error: Autodesk Viewer sometimes causes an error when using distance calculation tool

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Autodesk Viewer sometimes causes an error in developer console when using distance calculation tool.

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'faces')
```

It seems that this error doesn't affect the viewer function. How can you fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide such a model (a non-confidential one) and the info on what exactly to measure?